# Gibbs sampling from a 2D Gaussian

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, gibbs

Suppose $\textbf x \sim\mathcal N\left(\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1&-1/2\\-1/2&1\end{pmatrix}\right)$. Derive the full conditionals $p(x_1|x_2)$ and $p(x_2|x_1)$. Implement the Gibbs sampling algorithm and plot the 1d marginals $p(x_1)$ and $p(x_2)$ as histograms. Superimpose a plot of the exact marginals.

The conditionals are $x_1|x_2\sim \mathcal N(1+(-1/2)(1)(x_2-1), 1-(-1/2)(-1/2))$ and
$x_2|x_1=\mathcal N(1+(-1/2)(1)(x_1-1), 1-(-1/2)(1)(-1/2))$. So that $p(x_1|x_2)=\mathcal N(3/2-\frac12 x_2, 3/4)$ and $p(x_2|x_1)=\mathcal N(3/2 - \frac 12 x_1, 3/4)$.

Starting at $x^0_2=0$. And knowing that the marginals are $p(x_1)=p(x_2)=\mathcal N(1,1)$. The MLE from my Gibbs samples is $\mathcal N(1, 3/4)$.

*Edit: My reasoning is that we know the samples are $(x_1, x_2)$ from a multivariate gaussian, so we can use the regular MLE formula for the marginals, which would also be gaussian. $\hat\mu_{1,\text{MLE}}=\bar x, \hat\sigma^2_{MLE}=\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N(x_i-\bar x)^2$. So the $x_1$ samples should be $N(1,1)$, but they're not, they're $N(1, 3/4)$.*

So is it because the marginal is not equal to the conditional; if so how to get the marginal from the Gibbs samples?

Code:

```
x20 = 0
x1 <- c()
x2 <- c()
x1[1] = rnorm(1, 3/2 - 1/2 * x20, 3/4)
x2[1] <- rnorm(1, 3/2 - 1/2 * x1[1], 3/4)
for (i in 2:10000) {
  x1[i]=rnorm(1, 3/2 - 1/2 * x2[i-1], 3/4)
  x2[i] =rnorm(1, 3/2 - 1/2 * x1[i], 3/4)
}
x1 <- x1[2500:10000]
x2 <- x2[2500:10000]

mu1 <- mean(x1)
var1 <- mean((x1 - mean(x1))^2)
mu2 <- mean(x2)
var2 <- mean((x2 - mean(x2))^2)
mu1
var1
mu2
var2
hist(x1, freq=FALSE)
curve(dnorm(x, 1, 1), col="blue", add=TRUE)
curve(dnorm(x, mu1, sqrt(var1)), col="red", add=TRUE)
hist(x2, freq=FALSE)
curve(dnorm(x, 1, 1), col="blue", add=TRUE)
curve(dnorm(x, mu2, sqrt(var2)), col="red", add=TRUE)
```

[image]

How to get the marginals? Or did I derive the conditionals incorrectly?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by the "MLE from my Gibbs Samples" refers to and how you derive that distribution?

Comment: Re "the $x_1$ samples should be $N(1,1)$": yes, that's what your first line means (among other things).  Thus, whatever reasoning you are using to deduce this statement must be fallacious.

Comment: The argument about the sample being from the MLE recentred Normal distribution is completely wrong. The MLE is not equal to the true parameter $(\mu,\sigma)$ but the sample remains distributed from the Normal distribution with the true parameter $(\mu,\sigma)$. (I further do not understand on _which_ sample is this MLE based. The exercise is pure simulation and does not involve an observed _sample_.)